# Print PDF file with Javascript in all popular browser

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, iframe

How to print a PDF file using Javascript across all popular browser?
I have done quite extensive research on this question and there is no real solutions.

First approach is to use iFrame, however, iFrame is not a good practise. Code is listed as following.

```
function printIframePdf(){
    window.frames["printf"].focus();
    try {
        window.frames["printf"].print();
    }
    catch(e){
        window.print();
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

Second approach is to use `<embed>` or `<object>`tag to display pdf and use `document.getElementById(pdfID).print()` to print. However, Chrome does not support this function. Code is listed as following.

```
function printObjectPdf() {
    document.getElementById('idPdf').Print();
}
```

Is there a good solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you consider PDF.js?

https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/

This is web standards-based platform.

Comment: Thanks, Matteo. That's a very heavy solution. Is there simpler way to do it?

Comment: One option would be to force download of your PDF from the web and add document level javascript which will execute this.print()  when it opens in Acrobat - obviously this requires user to have Acrobat, not some other PDF viewer without JS support

Comment: PDF.JS  is very good even in case the client doesn't have Acrobat or whatever program to open PDF. The lack could be on old computers (because of performance of processing JS)